Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen ISchemaGenerator.GenerateSchema generates an empty schema
I'm using Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger 6.6.2 in a .NET 8 service with a custom IOperationFilter to generate request examples for my API. In my filter, I'm trying to manually generate a schema for types which are not located in my SchemaRepository using the ISchemaGenerator.GenerateSchema(Type modelType, SchemaRepository schemaRepository) method, but the manually generated schema for the type is always empty, with no properties populated.
This is how I am generating the schema:
private OpenApiSchema GenerateSpecializedSchema(Type modelType, SchemaRepository schemaRepository, ISchemaGenerator schemaGenerator)
{
    OpenApiSchema schema = schemaGenerator.GenerateSchema(modelType, schemaRepository);
    // Schema is empty at this point
    return schema;
}

Using it in my custom IOperationFilter
public class MyCustomOperationFilter : IOperationFilter
{
    public void Apply(OpenApiOperation operation, OperationFilterContext context)
    {
        // Retrieve the exact type I want from a custom attribute (details omitted for simplicity)
        var modelType = ...;

        // Generate the schema for the specified type
        var schema = GenerateSpecializedSchema(modelType, context.SchemaRepository, context.SchemaGenerator);
    }
}


An example of class type I'm trying to generate a schema for looks like this:
public class MyClassExample
{
    public string PropertyA { get; set; }
    public string PropertyB { get; set; }
}

When I inspect the generated schema, it is empty — meaning there are no properties inside. However, MyClassExample is a simple POCO with a few public properties, and I would expect these properties to appear in the generated schema.
The resulted OAS JSON file looks like this for MyClassExample:
 ...
 "components": {
    "schemas": {
      "MyClassExample": {}
       ...
    }
 ...

What I've tried:

I've debugged the code, and it seems like ISchemaGenerator.GenerateSchema returns an empty OpenApiSchema without any properties.
I've verified that modelType is correct and points to MyClassExample.
I've checked that the type is public and accessible.

I am expecting to receive a schema with the properties of the model type.

I test in my local and here is the structure of my test project and test result.

Test Result

Here is the detailed code
1.MyCustomOperationFilter.cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApiExplorer;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;
using Microsoft.OpenApi.Models;
using Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen;

namespace MyTest
{
    public class MyCustomOperationFilter : IOperationFilter
    {
        private readonly SchemaGeneratorOptions _schemaGeneratorOptions;

        public MyCustomOperationFilter(IOptions<SchemaGeneratorOptions> schemaGeneratorOptions)
        {
            _schemaGeneratorOptions = schemaGeneratorOptions.Value;
        }
        public void Apply(OpenApiOperation operation, OperationFilterContext context)
        {
            foreach (var parameterDescription in context.ApiDescription.ParameterDescriptions)
            {
                var parameterType = parameterDescription.Type;
                var schema = GenerateSpecializedSchema(parameterType, context.SchemaRepository, context.SchemaGenerator);

                var openApiParameter = operation.Parameters.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Name == parameterDescription.Name);
                if (openApiParameter != null)
                {
                    openApiParameter.Schema = schema;
                }
            }

            foreach (var responseType in context.ApiDescription.SupportedResponseTypes)
            {
                var returnType = responseType.Type;
                var schema = GenerateSpecializedSchema(returnType, context.SchemaRepository, context.SchemaGenerator);

                var statusCode = responseType.StatusCode.ToString();

                if (operation.Responses.ContainsKey(statusCode))
                {
                    var response = operation.Responses[statusCode];
                    response.Content["application/json"] = new OpenApiMediaType
                    {
                        Schema = schema
                    };
                }
                else
                {
                    operation.Responses[statusCode] = new OpenApiResponse
                    {
                        Description = "Success",
                        Content = new Dictionary<string, OpenApiMediaType>
                        {
                            ["application/json"] = new OpenApiMediaType
                            {
                                Schema = schema
                            }
                        }
                    };
                }
            }
        }

        private OpenApiSchema GenerateSpecializedSchema(Type modelType, SchemaRepository schemaRepository, ISchemaGenerator schemaGenerator)
        {
            var schemaId = _schemaGeneratorOptions.SchemaIdSelector(modelType);

            if (schemaRepository.Schemas.ContainsKey(schemaId))
            {
                schemaRepository.Schemas.Remove(schemaId);
            }

            OpenApiSchema schema = schemaGenerator.GenerateSchema(modelType, schemaRepository);
            return schema;
        }
    }
}

2.Program.cs
using MyTest;
using Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddControllers();
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();

builder.Services.Configure<SchemaGeneratorOptions>(options =>
{
    options.SchemaIdSelector = type => type.FullName;
});

builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
{
    c.OperationFilter<MyCustomOperationFilter>();
    c.CustomSchemaIds(type => type.FullName); 
});



var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();

3.MyClassExample.cs
namespace MyTest.Models
{
    public class MyClassExample
    {
        public string? PropertyA { get; set; }
        public string? PropertyB { get; set; }
    }
}

4.WeatherForecastController.cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using MyTest.Models;

namespace MyTest.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    public class WeatherForecastController : ControllerBase
    {
        private static readonly string[] Summaries = new[]
        {
            "Freezing", "Bracing", "Chilly", "Cool", "Mild", "Warm", "Balmy", "Hot", "Sweltering", "Scorching"
        };

        private readonly ILogger<WeatherForecastController> _logger;

        public WeatherForecastController(ILogger<WeatherForecastController> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        [HttpGet(Name = "GetWeatherForecast")]
        public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> Get()
        {
            return Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index => new WeatherForecast
            {
                Date = DateOnly.FromDateTime(DateTime.Now.AddDays(index)),
                TemperatureC = Random.Shared.Next(-20, 55),
                Summary = Summaries[Random.Shared.Next(Summaries.Length)]
            })
            .ToArray();
        }

        // Enable MyClassExample
        [HttpGet("GetMyClassExample")]
        public IEnumerable<MyClassExample> Get1()
        {
            return Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index => new MyClassExample
            {
                PropertyA = DateOnly.FromDateTime(DateTime.Now.AddDays(index)).ToString(),
                PropertyB = Random.Shared.Next(-20, 55).ToString()
            })
            .ToArray();
        }
    }
}

